# Showing the text after an equal sign with regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to know if there is a code, preferable Regexp, that can get all the text after an equal sign.

For example:

3+4=7

Results:

7

Is this even possible? I hope so, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is it preferable to use a regex? Just split on the `"="`. In any case, you need to say what language you're using; there are differences.

Comment: It would be more useful if you said *why* it wouldn't work, because obviously the way you worded the question, it would work perfectly, and be easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var s = "3+4=7"; 
var regex = /=(.+)/; // match '=' and capture everything that follows
var matches = s.match(regex);
if (matches) {
    var match = matches[1];  // captured group, in this case, '7'
    document.write(match);
}
```

Working example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F78Nk/).

Comment: How do I use regexp anyways? Can I get a jsfiddle example

Comment: I've written an example in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`/=(.*)/` should suffice, since it will find a result on the first =.

Other possibilities (can be transcribed into languages other than Perl too)

```
$x = "foo=bar";
print "$'" if $x =~ /(?<==)/;   # $' = that after the matched string
print "$&" if $x =~ /(?<==).*/; # $& = that which matched
print "$1" if $x =~ /=(.*)/;    # first suggestion from above
```

Comment: +1 for simple. I'd suggest explaining to the OP that the text will be captured in Group 1.